# How to make a conditional while loop repeat the procedure n times?

Tags: python, iteration

I have this simple number guessing game and what I would like to do is, once the user guesses the correct random number, I want to store the count number of the trials in a list. Let's say if the user finds the number in 9 trials, 9 is going to be stored in a list, but I want to run the game 3 times, and store those 3 trials in a list then get the average of it. The part I am having problem is once the user finds in n times, it sores it in a list, but does not continue. It stops after 1 game. How do I make it run 3 times? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
import random
def main():

    num = random.randint(1, 1000)

    my_guess = 0
    counter = 0
    list_trial = []
    num_times = 3
    j = 0

    while my_guess != num and j < num_times:
        my_guess = int(input('Make a guess  -->   '))
        counter += 1
        if my_guess < num:
            print('Too low!')
        elif my_guess > num:
            print('Too high!')
        else:
            print('Finally, you got it !')
            print('It took you ' + str(counter) + ' tries...')
            list_trial.append(counter)

    print(list_trial)   #prints the number of trials...
    print(sum(list_trial / len(list_trial)))   # prints the average of the trials...

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems with your code:

- You are not incrementing j in your while loop. You should have a `j+=1` somewhere in your loop.
- Your last print statement has a misplaced parenthesis. It should be `print(sum(list_trial) / len(list_trial))`.
- Lastly, assuming you are incrementing j, your while loop logic (`while my_guess != num and j < num_times`) exits upon the first valid guess.

Putting all this together:

```
num_times = 3
j = 0
list_trial = []

while j < num_times:
    my_guess = 0
    counter = 0
    num = random.randint(1, 3)
    while my_guess != num:
        my_guess = int(input('Make a guess  -->   '))
        counter += 1
        if my_guess < num:
            print('Too low!')
        elif my_guess > num:
            print('Too high!')
        else:
            print('Finally, you got it !')
            print('It took you ' + str(counter) + ' tries...')
            list_trial.append(counter)
    j += 1

print(list_trial)  # prints the number of trials...
print(sum(list_trial) / len(list_trial))  # prints the average of the trials...
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have totally forgotten about incrementing the j lol. I was losing my mind here. :) Thank you again !

Comment: @Darren76 it happens to all of us. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can split your `while` to two separted `while`s. one for checking the `num_times` and the inner `while` for the game itself, like this:

```
list_trial = []
num_times = 3
j = 0

while j < num_times:
    num = random.randint(1, 1000)
    my_guess = 0
    counter = 0
    while my_guess != num:
        my_guess = int(input('Make a guess  -->   '))
        counter += 1
        if my_guess < num:
            print('Too low!')
        elif my_guess > num:
            print('Too high!')
        else:
            print('Finally, you got it !')
            print('It took you ' + str(counter) + ' tries...')
            list_trial.append(counter)
    j += 1

print(list_trial)   #prints the number of trials...
print(sum(list_trial) / len(list_trial))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the length of your list as the check in your while loop, then you won't need to have a `j` variable at all:

```
import random

list_trial = []
num_times = 3

while len(list_trial) < num_times:
    num = random.randint(1, 1000)
    my_guess = 0
    counter = 0
    while my_guess != num:
        my_guess = int(input('Make a guess  -->   '))
        counter += 1
        if my_guess < num:
            print('Too low!')
        elif my_guess > num:
            print('Too high!')
        else:
            print('Finally, you got it !')
            print('It took you ' + str(counter) + ' tries...')
            list_trial.append(counter)

print(list_trial)   #prints the number of trials...
print(sum(list_trial / len(list_trial)))   # prints the average of the trials...
```